# Deformed shapes after using wedge_buffer as Symbol layer in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, buffer, polygon-creation, geometry-generator

I'm trying to display `"field of view"` cones on the map, using Geometry Generator as Symbol layer:

```
wedge_buffer($geometry, dir, specs_angle, specs_distance/200000, 0)
```

`"dir"` : values are between 0 and 360°
`"specs_angle"` : mostly 50-120°
`"specs_distance"` : ~20-30 (meters)

The only issue I can see so far is that the radius (`"specs_distance"`) needs to be divided by a factor of 1000'000 as shown in the example, despite the project unit being the same (meters).

Instead of wedges, I get deformed shapes like here:

[image]

Radius is not consistent, it's obvious at first sight, and the angle displayed isn't exactly the same as entered in the wedge_buffer function.

The North is at 45° in this picture, but rotating the map in QGIS doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: `def wedge_buffer(centre, radius, azimuth, opening_angle, inner_radius = 0, angle_resolution = 10):` I don't think you have entered the parameters correctly.  https://github.com/Septima/qgis-wedgebuffer/blob/master/src/WedgeBuffer/wedge_buffer_implementation.py

Comment: also this `wedge = wedge_buffer_implementation.wedge_buffer(centre, radius, azimuth, wedgeAngle, innerRadius)` here https://github.com/Septima/qgis-wedgebuffer/blob/eef22fed423d5edcc8f11d8d066f2c6052b39cca/src/WedgeBuffer/wedge_buffer_algorithm.py#L143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a projection issue: your wedge buffers are not symmetric. You very likely have:

- The layer in a geographic CRS like WGS84, `EPSG:4326` - that's why you have to divide the distance as units are in degrees
- The project set to another (projected?) CRS like WebMercator, `EPSG:3857`. If so: EPSG:3857 ist not ideal for many tasks, so think about which CRS to use for your region of interest.

*Project CRS in `EPSG:3857` with wedge-buffers on a point-layer in `EPSG:4326`. In red: deformed buffers, created in `EPSG:4326`; in blue: transformed with geometry genertor (=solution 2), based on the same values for `azimuth` and `width`:*

[image]

### Solution 1

Reproject your layer to a projected CRS and best set the project's CRS to the same CRS.

### Solution 2

Use Geometry generator and transform the geometries using this expression.

```
transform (
    wedge_buffer (
        transform (
            $geometry,
            'EPSG:4326',
            'EPSG:3857'
        ),
        dir, 
        specs_angle, 
        specs_distance
    ),
    'EPSG:3857',
    'EPSG:4326'
)
```

### Solution 3

Set the project CRS to the same as the layer's CRS.

Comment: OK, thanks, I used the Reproject Layer Processing toolbox, had to rebuild the joins, reload styles, etc... Not sure why the new layers created in this project were on different CRS than the project itself, doesn't make much sense.

Comment: When you create a layer, you set the CRS. Otherwise,  QGIS uses the default - normally `EPSG:4326`. You know you can copy/paste styles etc. From one layer to another one?

Comment: Yes, I thought QGis would just use the project's CRS 'by default' for new layers, but of course it's not always possible (ie csv with long, lat fields can not be imported straight as flat 3857 CRS layers). To keep it simple without a fit for all solution, some layers will have to use different CRS... For the styles I save/load .qss files, which works well after recreating layers, but I still need to manually set joins, diagrams, correct some encoding issues etc.

Comment: So then maybe solution 2 is best for you: you can keep your layer in 4326 and only change Geometry generator's expression to get correct wedge buffers.